# cant set bookmark range in C# version using Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am converting a vb.net set of helpers to c#. The following snippet works fine in VB.Net

```
para2 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range)
```

where para2 is oftype Word.Paragraph

the converted c# code to set the bookmark range which i see in numerous articles is

```
var bookmarkRange= oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item((object)"\\endofdoc").Range;
var para2 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(bookmarkRange);
```

ReSharper says this needs to use an indexed property, which when changed converts that to

```
var bookmarkRange = oDoc.Bookmarks.Item[(object)"\\endofdoc"].Range;
```

Neither version builds, the error is

> Error 1   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmarks' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmarks' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) F:\BATLGroup\AzureStorageContainer\AzureStorageContainer\AzureStorageContainer\AzureHelpers\OfficeAppHelpers.cs 19  44  AzureStorageContainer

I am referencing

> Assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
>       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

Any help appreciated.

Extra Credit:

```
  do
        {
            bookmarkRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;
            bookmarkRange.InsertAfter("A line of text");
            bookmarkRange.InsertParagraphAfter();
        } while (pos >= bookmarkRange.Information[WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage]);
```

This section is erring on bookmarkRange.Information. It is saying you cant compare an int and an object. wdVertical.... is supposed to return a number indicating distance from top of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# equivalent of `oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range` would be:

```
oDoc.Bookmarks["\\endofdoc"].Range
```

... and this is because C# doesn't implement the `Item` property like VB does, according to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> [...] The C# language uses the keyword to define the indexers instead of
>   implementing the Item property. Visual Basic implements Item as a
>   default property, which provides the same indexing functionality.

**Update**:

The line `bookmarkRange.Information[WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage]` actually return a float, so you'll need to cast it to compare it, e.g.:

```
pos >= (float)bookmarkRange.Information[WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage]);
```

That is assuming pos is of a type comparable to float.

Comment: wow, of every possible iteration i tried, including numerous with the brackets, I'm stupified I missed that one. I have one other issue. Please see update in post if you please.

Comment: In C# the \ has to be escaped so it's "\\endofdoc"

Comment: See, I missed that one! Updated.